# JS Test output showing up in console when it shouldn't be in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have a form, and my JS is validating input upon submission. I have some test data that should only appear in the console if 'test=true' is in the query string. However this data is showing up despite that not being the case in some browsers.

Works: FF;
Does not work: Chrome, IE

```
$.each($(".required"), function(){
    var test = false;
    if($.contains(location.search.toString(),"test=true")){
        console.log("test activated");
        console.log("location.search: ",location.search);
        console.log("test: ",test)
        test = true;
    }
            console.log("test after: ",test);
    if(test){console.log("---- ", $(this).attr("name"), "---- ");}
}
```

Here's the output:

```
test activated 
location.search:   
test:  false 
--------------  fname ------------
```

As you can see, location.search is nothing and 'test' is equal to false, so nothing should be logged, right? Am I missing something here?

Comment: what does changing the line `console.log("location.search: ",location.search);` to `console.log("location.search: ",location.search.toString());` do, does the output change?

Comment: The reason you are printing `test:  false` is because you first print it, then set it.  Printing it there is useless because it will print the original value of `false` from the first line.  Also, your sample output is missing the output from `console.log("test after: ",test);`.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @DeclanCook Nothing. I wasn't sure if it would affect anything, it didn't, but decided to add it here in case someone told me to add it.

Comment: @MosheKatz My bad, it's true, so it'd look like "test after: true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation on `jQuery.contains`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/), it should be used to "check to see if a DOM element is a descendant of another DOM element", not comparing strings.

You can use String.indexOf instead:

```
if(location.search.indexOf("test=true") != -1){
```